# MySQL Join 3 Tables with Count

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have the following tables:

**users**

- id
- username
- first_name
- email

**students**

- id
- user_id

**payments**

- id
- student_id
- is_paid
- date

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT users.username, users.first_name, users.email,
    COUNT(payments.id) as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.id AND payments.is_paid = 0
WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser';
```

When the username exists and there are not pending payments, it returns:

```
| username | first_name | email                | pending_payments |

| testuser | test       | testuser@example.com |        0         |
```

When the username exists and there are 2 pending payments, it returns:

```
| username | first_name | email                 | pending_payments |

| testuser2| test2      | testuser@2example.com |        2         |
```

But when the username does not exists, it returns:

```
| username | first_name | email              | pending_payments   |

| NULL     | NULL       | NULL               |         0          |
```

Instead, when the username does not exists, I want as result:

Empty set.

How can I modify my query to get the expected results?
(keep the behavior when user exists, but returns Empty set when does not exists, instead of a row will NULL values).

See SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab424/11

**EDIT**
**A working solution was provided**:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab424/72

Comment: Try to Use Inner Join

Comment: So, just to be sure, do you just want "empty set" when username does not exist, otherwise you want the first 3 columns?

Comment: yes, if no username, empty set, if username exists, return the right pending_payments

Comment: Please define your expectation of an "empty set"?  if there is no row in users to match the where clause you will get nothing returned (no column headings, just nothing). How does this differ to your "empty set"?

Comment: If you see the Fiddle, the 3rd case should return no row, instead of a row with Null values. and the other cases need to keep the result that they had.

Comment: Why is your second join a left join? It complicates things because rows with nulls are introduced for rows from the first join that don't have an appropriate students.id when you really have no interest in such rows.

Comment: Are the tables in 1:many relationship?  Or many:many?  With the latter, the `COUNT(*)` will probably be bigger than it is supposed to be.

Comment: @RickJames Looks like both relations are 1:n because of `students.user_id` and `payments.student_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate functions like `COUNT(*)` always generate one row if no GROUP BY clause is used. So use a GROUP BY clause, if you want an empty result:

```
SELECT users.username, users.first_name, users.email,
    COUNT(payments.id) as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.id AND payments.is_paid = 0
WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser3'
GROUP BY users.username, users.first_name, users.email;
```

Note that you will get one row per user with that username. If `username` is not UNIQUE and you want to get one row for all users with the same `username`, you can use the HAVING clause instead of GROUP BY to "remove" the "empty" row.

```
SELECT users.username, COUNT(payments.id) as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.id AND payments.is_paid = 0
WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser3'
HAVING username IS NOT NULL;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab424/73)

This has nothing to do with the LEFT or any JOIN. It is just how aggregate functions work (in MySQL), and you will see the same behavior with a simple example without joins like

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE username = 'testuser3';

| username | COUNT(*) |
|----------|----------|
|   (null) |        0 |
```

Note that this query is not SQL standard compliant, and in strict mode you will get an error, because `username` is selected without beeng listed in the GROUP BY clause. ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aab424/79)).

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) says:

> If you name columns to select in addition to the `COUNT()` value, a
>   `GROUP BY` clause should be present that names those same columns.
>   Otherwise, the following occurs:
>
> - If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs:
>     [...]
> - If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not enabled, the query is processed by
>     treating all rows as a single group, but the value selected for each
>     named column is indeterminate. The server is free to select the value
>     from any row:
>     [...]

Again: "The server is free to select the value from any row". But since there is no matching row, it returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you receive "null" response is due to the `LEFT JOIN` statements. A Left join gets done, even if parameters do not match in that table, because they might make up columns in another (joined) table. To show only results that match criteria, use an `INNER JOIN` statement.

Also, you wish to `COUNT(*)` payments due by username, you should `GROUP BY` username I should think.

Try the following (untested, sorry, not in front of pc with editor on it)

```
SELECT u.username, u.first_name, u.email, COUNT(p.is_paid) as pending_payments
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN students s ON u.id = s.user_id
  INNER JOIN payments p ON s.user_id = p.student_id
WHERE u.username LIKE '%testuser%'
      AND u.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.username
ORDER BY p.is_paid DESC, u.username ASC
```

Additionally, if you'd want to show only the results that have open pending payments you could add a `HAVING` statement *after* the `GROUP BY`, such as

```
HAVING u.pending_payments > 0
```

Tested with the following setup:

[image: Demo setup with demo data]

Below showing the query results. Second query does not have the `HAVING` statement.

[image: Showing queries with results]

Answer (score 1):

I think the NULL values found for username etc. is mostly because of the missing group by in your queries.

I think it should work using:

```
SELECT users.username, 
       users.first_name, 
       users.email,
       SUM(COALESCE( p.is_paid = 0, 0))  as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students s on s.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN payments p on p.student_id = s.id
WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser3'
GROUP BY users.username, 
         users.first_name, 
         users.email;
```

And when leaving out the WHERE line, it will list for all the users:

```
SELECT users.username, 
       users.first_name, 
       users.email,
       SUM(COALESCE( p.is_paid = 0, 0))  as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students s on s.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN payments p on p.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY users.username, 
         users.first_name, 
         users.email;
```

It will mention all users, even those who don't have any payment (pending or not) or users who are not listed in the Students table

Comment: Your solution works  but Paul Spiegel sent a working solution before ;)

Answer (score 0):

You obviously has users with NULL username in `users` table.  You can filter out the NULL value in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT users.username, users.first_name, users.email,
    COUNT(payments.is_paid = 0) as pending_payments
FROM users
LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.id
WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser' AND users.username IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Adding users.username IS NOT NULL not solve the issue

If I search for an user that not exists: 'dksahdaskjldha', it will return 
| NULL     | NULL       | NULL               |         0          |

instead of Empty set.

Comment: @smartin If username existed, how can it returns NULL in the username column?

Comment: the previous comment (that I later commented) was related with your fist reply, that you later edited

Comment: That query doesn't have the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant use IS NOT NULL ?

```
 SELECT users.username, users.first_name, users.email,
        COUNT(payments.id) as pending_payments
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN students ON users.id = students.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.student_id = students.id AND payments.is_paid = 0
    WHERE users.username LIKE 'testuser' and users.username is NOT NULL;
```